# Passing .pem and .key files in cURL doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: plugins, curl

I'm building a payment gateway plugin for *woocommerce* which requires sending an XML request via `cURL`, encrypted with private key.

I'm using the following code:

```
$xml_request    ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

$test_URL       = 'https://my-gateway.com';
// Here is where I change the file paths
$certfile       = '/clientcert.pem';
$keyfile        = '/clientkey.key';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $test_URL );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . $certfile );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . $keyfile );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: text/xml' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_request );
$ch_result = curl_exec( $ch );


// Check for errors
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $ch_result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 200:
            break;
        default:
            $ch_result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;
            break;
    }
}

curl_close( $ch );

echo $ch_result;
```

The problem is that `curl` can't find the certificate or key files no matter what path I use - I've tried absolute, and relative paths.
I've changed the `.pem` and `.key` file locations (tried theme directory, plugin directory, and root).
I've changed permissions to full.

But still I get the error
`58: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)`

Which means the file is not found or corrupt, while I'm sure it isn't, since **when I copy this code to a php file outside WordPress and run it, it works**.

I can overcome this issue by redirecting the user to a page outside WordPress, but I'd prefer to run it all from one place.
How can this be done?

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark but have you tried adding them to the mime_types filter?  See the filter run on line 1885 of wp-includes/functions.php.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBartel, I've just tried adding them, but unfortunately, with no success. 'pem' => 'application/x-pem-file', 'key' => 'application/pkcs8',

Comment: I think issue is caused `getcwd()`, use [plugin_dir_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path). Also it's recommended to use WP's HTTP API.

Comment: @Mamaduka, Thank you very much. That did the trick. I'm going to post the answer. In regards to HTTP API, I really want to know more about it, but unfortunately, there's a lack of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Mamaduka comment; the following changes resolve it:

Use `plugin_dir_path()` to get the filesystem directory path:

```
$certfile = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/clientcert.pem';
$keyfile = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/clientkey.key';
```

Then remove `getcwd()`.

If you want to use it in your theme use `TEMPLATEPATH`

I also want to mention that using the following paths previously **did not** work:

```
WP_PLUGIN_URL . "/" . plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/clientkey.key'
```

nor:

```
get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/lib/cert/clientcert.pem'
```

nor:

```
'http://my-web-site.com/clientcert.pem'
```